Two-way Entity reference, programmatically
I'm building a custom module to handle two custom entities which extend ContentEntityBase: Organization and Contact. Organization can have multiple contacts, while contact can belong to one organization.
I have defined baseFieldDefinitions method for each entity:
Organization:
$fields['contacts'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('Contact'))
      ->setDescription(t('Name of the contact'))
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'mymodule_contact')
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'entity_reference_label',
        'weight' => -3,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
        'weight' => -3,
      ])
      ->setRequired(true)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);

Contact:
$fields['organization'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('Organization'))
      ->setDescription(t('Name of the organization'))
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'mymodule_organization')
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'above',
        'type' => 'entity_reference_label',
        'weight' => -3,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
        'weight' => -3,
      ])
      ->setRequired(true)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);

When I assign contacts to organization via Organization entity form, the Contact entity reference records are stored in mymodule_organization__contacts table. However, when I'm adding a new contact via Contact entity form, the Organization relationship is not recorded. mymodule_contacts will assign organization value to the selected organization_id, however, the record is not added to mymodule_organization__contacts table.
ChatGPT and other resources are suggesting to write a hook or to write custom save() method inside Contact entity. However, I find it hard to believe that Drupal didn't foresee handling one-to-many, belongs-to-one without hooks/custom save methods. There's got to be a better way, right?

Drupal 7 has the excellent Relation module to do this.  Unfortunately, nothing similar has been built for Drupal 8+; the module was basically abandoned as shown here: https://www.drupal.org/project/relation/issues/1988922

The CER module should do the trick for D8+ with this patch https://www.drupal.org/project/cer/issues/3073892

I ended up writing the custom save method. Inside Contact entity class:
  public function save()
  {
    // save contact entity (this will generate id for the contact record)
    parent::save();

    // load Organization entity based on form selection
    $organization = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('mymodule_organization')
      ->load($this->get('organization')->target_id);

    // save contact entity to organization as entity reference
    $organization->contacts[] =  ['target_id' => $this->id()];;
    $organization->save();

  }


That's not all you need to maintain a two-way reference. But most times you don't need to save references both ways, you can get the data for the missing direction via an entity query.
